# Why do I get a GRUB error after deleting the Linux partition?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, grub

I had a dual-boot setup with Windows 7 and Windows Vista. I used Easus Partition Manager and shrank my Windows 7 partition. In the empty space, I installed Linux Mint. I decided I didn't want it anymore,  I simply deleted the Linux Mint partition. Now when I boot, all I get is this:

```
GRUB loading.
error: no such partition
grub rescue>
```

I don't have my Windows 7 install disk because it was pre-installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have any MS operating system so I could not try this myself, from [this page](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html) on the windows 7 forums - though - it seems like the *startup repair utility* (SRU) is also included in OEM distros of the system.

My understanding of that page is that you can then boot, with the help of a liveCD or usb drive into your existing windows 7 and from there run the SRU. If my understanding is correct, then you can most probably boot your system from the linux installation CD you originally used to install linux or by means of a dedicated tool, like the [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/). Two scenarios that might fit your bill seem to be [this](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/w/index.php5?title=UninstallGRUB) and [this](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/w/index.php5?title=Howto_Boot_Windows_without_problems).

Another less elegant solution would be to repair Grub [the Super Grub Disk comes in help in this scenario too] and let GRUB launch Windows 7 for you.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing you can do is put a Windows 7 disk in to your machine and boot from it, then click repair and go to Command Prompt.

Navigate to c:\boot and run this command:

```
bootsect /nt60 c:
bootsect /nt60 sys
bootsect /nt60 all
bootsect /nt60 sys /mbr
```

Try them all until your system boots.

Comment: comment from [Kris](http://superuser.com/users/37644/kris): bootsect /nt60 sys /mbr worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thanks alot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: C:\boot didn't exist on my Win7 machine, but the commands above worked fine at C:\.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[Bootsect.exe Modifies the Bootsector Not the MBR!! | The NeoSmart Files](http://neosmart.net/blog/2007/bootsectexe-modifies-the-bootsector-not-the-mbr/)

The above prompts did not work for me. I am running Windows Vista and deleted Linux partitions and was dealing with the grub error at start up. The above link worked for me.

After booting using a recovery DVD and entering repair and command prompt enter the following.

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr 
bootrec.exe /fixboot 
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing you can do is put a Windows 7 disk in to your machine and boot from it.

After you choose your language and keyboard layout, click *Repair* in the bottom left and go to *Startup Repair* – if it doesn't do this automatically.

This should be able to re create the Windows bootloader and all the system files required to start Windows again.

Comment: I don't have a Windows 7 disk.

Comment: @nironan12: borrow one.