# Unable to start computer after uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a GRUB error after deleting the Linux partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/74017/why-do-i-get-a-grub-error-after-deleting-the-linux-partition)

I was dual booting with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I recently uninstalled Ubuntu and deleted it's partition, which is currently free space. I was unable to extend the Windows 7 partition, so I restarted. However, upon restart I have come to this screen:

error: no such partition.
grub rescue>

What do I do from here?

I do not have a Windows Installation or Repair Disk, but I do have a Ubuntu 11.04 disk which I used to install Ubuntu before.

Comment: However, I don't have a Windows Installation Disk. Is there software I can use from my Ubuntu disk? Or would it be easier to install Ubuntu again and dual-boot to get into Windows?

Comment: I guess EasyBCD would also do the job, but reinstalling Ubuntu will definitely fix your boot loader.

Comment: Alright, I found a way to download a legal copy of the Windows Installation Disk online, and now that I installed Ubuntu it's working again, but now I'll be able follow the directions in the other question. Thanks for pointing that out.