# GRUB uninstalled

Tags: grub

Before anyone jump into conclusion please read the whole thing.
Technical Details: Laptop : Toshiba - Satellite U500 HDD : u500

I had both Windows7 and ubuntu installed on my laptop. Since there was lot of unnecessary apps installed I decided to remove the whole OS and then put a fresh install of windows and Ubuntu.

Now here's what I did. I deleted the partition which contain the Ubuntu, knowing well that it would delete the GRUB and I will not be able to boot into windows. 
Nevertheless for the sheer curiosity of knowing the technical how, I decided to go ahead. Even if something goes wrong I could use my Repair disk and System recovery disk to install back windows.

I opened the disk management and deleted the linux partition. Then I restarted the system. I got the error message.
Now here starts the problem.
1. I cannot boot from my cd. I have no idea what is wrong with it, I used to watch movies and listened to music, and the drive worked fine, but it does not boot from my cd. After booting It keeps going back to the same error.

2. I thought my System image and recovery disks are at fault. So I got another windows 7 and Windows XP CD to install , again, but it will not boot.
3. So I thought I could boot from an USB and fix it. Unfortunately I don't have an option to boot from USB in my BIOS

I have no idea what to do. If only I could get my lap up and running.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: the error is the grub not found error

Comment: the GRUB file not found error

Comment: Why won't it boot from a CD? Tried the BIOS option for CD?

Comment: Yes I tried it but it won't work. I don't know if it is my  drive. It was working before all this hap. How can I check my laptop drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only deleted the linux partition, the MBR should be available which holds GRUB loader. But, you said you got an error message which you didn't include so based on the assumption you still get a prompt that shows (Grub> ....) after the computer boots. Check out this site [Uninstall Ubuntu](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2010/04/uninstall-linux.html)  and continue on from #3 - the link only supports grub legacy so the commands might or might not work.

Edited:
Seems like there is a similar question that was answered as well so check that out too. [link](https://superuser.com/questions/74017/why-do-i-get-a-grub-error-after-deleting-the-linux-partition)

Comment: He probably deleted `/boot` though

Comment: the error i mentioned was the Grub file not fund error i Guess. I dont remember the number, i guess it was error 12 or something. dont remember it.

Comment: I exactly dont remember as i dont have my laptop with me. But i will try out the steps in the link and let you know guys. Thanx for the immediate respose guys